# How to store and retrieve generic types

Tags: java, spring, generics, repository

I have a base repository interface and several repository interfaces extending it

```
interface VehicleRepository<T extends Vehicle> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
}
interface CarRepository extends VehicleRepository<Car> {
}
interface BikeRepository extends VehicleRepository<Bike> {
}
```

I also have several JPA specifications

```
class Specification<T extends Vehicle> implements Specification<T>{
}
class CarSpecification extends Specification<Car> {
}
class BikeSpecification extends Specification<Bike> {
}
```

Now I have a method that takes in different sub-types of `Vehicle` and I would like them to call their respective `Repository` and `Specification`. How should I do it?

I have tried wrapping them in `List<VehicleRepository<**SOMETHING**>> repoList` and `List<Specification<**SOMETHING**>> specList`, and would like to call them based on inputs

```
public class MyController {
    // @Autowire

    List<VehicleRepository<SOMETHING>> repoList;
    List<Specification<SOMETHING>> specList;

    @GetMapping("...")
    public ResponseEntity<List<? extends Vehicle>> getRawEventByCriteria(int vehicleType) {

        // What I am doing...
        if(vehicleType == 0) {
            List<Car> carList = ((VehicleRepository<Car>)repoList.get(0))
                .findAll((Specification<Car>)specList.get(0));
        } else if (vehicleType == 1) {
            List<Bike> bikeList = ((VehicleRepository<Bike>)repoList.get(1))
                .findAll((Specification<Bike>)specList.get(1));
        } else if (...) {
        }


        // What I want to do...
        List<vehicle.class> carList = ((AUTO SOMETHING)repoList.get(vehicleType))
            .findAll((AUTO SOMETHING)specList.get(vehicleType));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(retval, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

For reference, `findAll()` is defined as follow

```
interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
    List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);
}
```

Currently I am leaving SOMETHING as a rawtype, and it works without me having to cast everything, but I feel that it is not a good approach.

Comment: Your `if (param == integer)` construction smells. At a minimum, why not put `param=1` in your `GetMapping`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It is only there for reference. I have mapped each to an URL @GetMapping({"vehicle/car", "vehicle/bike", "vehicle/bus", etc}). Maybe I am not clear enough, but I am trying to dynamically use the specifications and repositories.